# Java Constructor Syntax Issue

Tags: java, class

I need a little help understanding constructors. It isnt full code I just need help understanding one part. My code is as follows:

School.java

```
public class School {
private String name;
private int busNumber;
enter code here
public School (String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSchoolName() {
    return name;
}

public int getBusNumber() {
    return bus Number;
}
```

---

Main.Java

```
System.out.println("Enter school number 1: ");
school1 = keyboard.nextLine();
School s1 = new School(school1);

System.out.println("Enter school number 2: ");
school2 = keyboard.nextLine();
School s2 = new School(school2);

System.out.println("School 1 is " + s1.getName());
System.out.println("School 2 is " + s2.getName());


 System.out.println("Enter the bus number 1: ");
 bus1 = keyboard.nextLine();
```

//Now what I want to do is send the bus numbers to getBusNumber.

//How do I send bus1 so I can use s1.getBusNumber(); to call the number later! I feel like this should be so easy but I can't grasp it or find how to do it anywhere. I also do not want to use a set function. Any syntax help would be awesome!!

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not want to use a set function? This seems like the perfect scenario for using one.

Comment: Its for an online class I am taking and its a defined School class which cant be change. For learning purposed I suppose, I wish I could do it my own way.

Comment: If the School class you provided is the the entire School class and you cannot change it, then there really isn't a way to set the busNumber in the object. Was there more to the class definition?

Comment: @RyanSobieralski So you want to set the value for `busNumber` without a setter?

Comment: You either set the value with a setter, or with a constructor parameter.  The alternative is to make the field public, which is a bad idea in general.

Comment: @RyanSobieralski Are you able to change anything in the School class? If you can't, you will have to show us all the codes in the class and not part of it.

Comment: "Make the code do something different without changing any of it" is a non-starter.  You're mis-understanding a requirement somewhere.

Comment: I fully agree with David, better show us the original question.

Comment: @David if he `extends` it he could technically override `getBusNumber()` and create another instance field and use that for the `return` of `getBusNumber()`...

Comment: @brso05: True.  Though he could also use reflection and pretty much have the keys to the kingdom.  I question what this class is teaching, though :)

Comment: @David I wish I was mis-understanding. I was given the Player Class and was told 'NOT TO CHANGE OR TOUCH" as the teacher will have the School class already in her project to build with students main.

That is really all the code. Nothing else that would be relevant to the code posted above. Unfortunately that's all the code I can show.

Question was to make two schools and add two buses to each school and print them out. Pretty basic, but came an without the setter. Im at a loss. Sorry for not much on it.

Comment: If the `School` class is not suppose to be changed, what's with the `enter code here` in your `School` class? By the way, no `Player` class was shown in your question.

Comment: @user3437460 That was a miss click when I was entering my code. Should of said School Class. Sorry

Comment: @RyanSobieralski: If the code in the question is the *exact* code you're using, then `enter code here` and `return bus Number` are going to result in compilation errors.  There really seems to be a mistake or misunderstanding somewhere in what you're presenting here.

Comment: @David I miss typed it pretty bad. the "enter code here" should not be there. Also it should be return busNumber. Other than that its spot on.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you posted here is not possible since the **busNumber** is declared private... 
You **need** (is a good practice) to define a setter for the member bus in the class School, you can to use public members but is not a good oop design since you need to change the access of the busNumber to public...

```
public void setBusNumber(int number) {
    this.busNumber = number;
}
```

and call it from the main java

```
System.out.println("Enter the bus number 1: ");
bus1 = keyboard.nextLine();
s1.setBusNumber(bus1);
```

**Be aware** you need to validate that what you read is a number because next line is returning strings...

Comment: Hmm, op says `I also do not want to use a set function`.

Comment: if you dont use setter you need to change the access of busnumber but i dont recommend this

Answer (score 1):

So if you need to not use a setter, you probably need to put it in the constructor.

So your constructor would be

```
public School (String name, int busNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.busNumber = busNumber
}
```

and your code would look like this

```
System.out.println("Enter school number 1: ");
school1 = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter school number 2: ");
school2 = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("School 1 is " + school1);
System.out.println("School 2 is " + school2);

System.out.println("Enter the bus number 1: ");
bus1 = keyboard.nextLine();

int intBus1 = Integer.parseInt(bus1)

School s1 = new School(school1, intBus1);
```

Then later in your code you can call get s1.getBusNumber() if needed